# How bulk move apps' data to SD card?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, external-sd

Ever since I bought my phone, I've never used SD card, since the storage is full. Using one now. I've got like 50-60+ apps and games. I manually can't go into each App's page and move to sd card.

There are apps to move the data to sd card, but as far as I've seen, there are no apps to automate the process or bulk move it.

Is there any app to do it? It's so hard to go into each app's page and wait for it to get moved to sd card.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575). With the correct phrasing and details provided, you might try your luck at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185).

Comment: Are you sure this could not just be done manually, once? Do you plan to do and undo and repeat the process many times? The process takes at most a few seconds per app. The 4 hours since your posting would have provided clearly enough time to have done so.

Comment: Well, since no app was there. Went to apps section, and moved out the 60MB+ games and some big sized apps. Hope that'd do for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use app like [app2sd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd) to easily see what program can be moved to SD card.

Comment: Yeah, but you can't move apps bulk. That was my query.